# keras model structure visualization

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I want to see keras model like [this](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/pull/4233#issuecomment-316954784). I used `K.get_session().graph` and get

tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Graph at 0x7f2a8b809400

but i to see this graph and save it. I am using tensorflow backend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install tensorboard

Import it

```
from keras.callbacks import TensorBoard
```

Load it into a variable

```
tbCallBack = TensorBoard(log_dir='Graph',
                         histogram_freq=10,
                         write_graph=True,
                         write_images=True)
```

And then use that as a callback at training:

```
model.fit(x, y, ...
          callbacks=[tbCallBack])
```

Make sure you have a made a directory called 'Graph' or whatever you want. Then before training run in terminal:

```
tensorboard --logdir Graph
```

And then you can see your graph in your browser

Comment: what is mean by directory in above answer. i am using current working directory. I am getting <keras.callbacks.History at 0x7f2a444fe9b0>  but not the graph

Comment: you have to make a directory called 'Graph' or whatever you want in you working directory and then use that as the argument for log_dir so tensorflow knows which directory to write the logs to

Comment: I followed above suggestions and get some events.out.tfevents.1506331517 files, but again not graph

Comment: did you open tensorboard in your browser after running that command?

Comment: if you have those files then the graph should show in tensorboard

Comment: getting error when open browser (http://0.0.0.0:6006/#scalars) No scalar data was found.

Comment: did you run with logdir agument and is there a directory called Graph in the directory you called tensorboard from?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155251/discussion-between-convolutionboy-and-hitesh).

Comment: Got the graph  very thnx